# Distinct items List, Set, HashSet, Lambda, Java 8

Tags: list, arraylist, java-8, set, hashset

I have three alternatives in order to obtain *Distinct* items in a `List`

```
return new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(someTypeList));

return new HashSet<>(someTypeList).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

return someTypeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What option You recommend to me and Why?

And if exist some single alternative, please tell me.

Comment: Preferrably with stream as `someTypeList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())` and without it the first of your statement. But the answers might just be opiinnion based to such questions.

Comment: IMO, I would go for this. `someTypeList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be consistent and not mix different approaches.

There’s the Collection API approach using either

- `new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(someTypeList))` or
- `new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(someTypeList))` when you want to retain the order

Then, there’s the Stream API approach

- `someTypeList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());` or
- `someTypeList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`
  when you need the result to be exactly an `ArrayList`

When `someTypeList` is an ordinary `List` implementation, the Collection approach is not only simpler, but also more efficient. The Stream API uses a `HashSet` internally anyway, when implementing `distinct()`, but the `collect` operation will suffer slightly from the abstraction, as it has no hint about the expected number of elements. In contrast, the `ArrayList` constructor will simply call `toArray` on the incoming `HashSet` and use the result as its backing array.

Things change when `someTypeList` is an unknown collection. In some scenarios, the Stream API may utilize the characteristics of the source to optimize the operation. If the source has already distinct elements, like with a `Set`, the overhead of `distinct()` will be eliminated. If the source is sorted, a different algorithm will be used for identifying duplicates, which doesn’t need a `HashSet`.

Since the Stream API encapsulates the actual implementation, it may receive future improvements without the need to adapt the client code. In contrast, the explicit Collection operation will always do exactly what it has been told to do, never benefiting from alternative implementation strategies.

Answer (score 0):

- First option
  doesn't retain original order of list and also has to construct set then copy to list.
- First option is better than second one as stream will have performance hit.
- Better than 3rd option, `someTypeList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

So if ordering is not a matter, then fierst option would be better. 
Also there are some third party libraries which provided better performance

e.g. [Guava ImmutableSet](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html)

`ImmutableSet.copyOf(listInts).asList();`

Hope it helps.